# CRM_FilteredTableName vs FilteredTableName VS Tablename in report SQL query

Tags: sql, report, dynamics-crm-2011, filtering, tablename

I understand that CRM_FilteredTableName will indicate prefiltering and the user will be prompted to enter the filter before running the report.

But what if I only use "FilteredTableName" , what difference does this make ? And how is it different than simply using my "Tablename" directly ?

Answer (score 0):

The difference is the context.

Excluding to query directly the table (like `SELECT firstname, lastname FROM Contact`) because it bypass CRM security model (this means the user must have SQL access and not CRM access and this is a wrong way to works with CRM) the other two options are:

1. Filtered Views (`SELECT firstname, lastname FROM FilteredContact`)
2. Prefiltering ( `SELECT firstname, lastname FROM FilteredContact AS CRMAF_Contact`)

As I wrote before the difference is the context, for example if open the Active Contacts View and launch the report the two queries will return different values, the Filtered View will return *all* the contacts (active and inactive) the user can access, the Prefiltering one will return only the *active* contacts the user can access.